# Building BoringSSL and Conscrypt and bundling with Android apk

Tags: android, security, openssl, boringssl

Im sure I saw an official guide on this on the [conscrypt](https://conscrypt.org/) project site but I cannot find this at all now.

Im wondering to the possibility of building BoringSSL locally and making it available via a bundled JCE `Provider` i.e. `Conscrypt`. I can see the BoringSSL project has [build instructions](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md) but cant see anything about bundling Conscrypt.

Did I dream this was a thing people were doing?

Maybe [updating the provider through GPlay](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html), is good enough, but I would like to avoid interfacing with GPlay services if poss (as it can be quite frustrating) but maybe in this case its the lesser of two evils!

Thanks for any info :)

EDIT: Just found [this](https://thebinarybin.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/updating-android-security-provider/) barebones guide to building conscrypt. Conscrypt has a JNI component but assuming this talks direct to BoringSSL. Quoting the BoringSSL intro

> We don’t recommend that third parties depend upon it. Doing so is likely to be frustrating because there are no guarantees of API or ABI stability.

How would I make sure that Conscrypt JNI -> BoringSSL are compatible versions I wonder?